# Unable to connect Firebase to my Xcode swift app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, xcode7

I followed all kinds of tutorials and tried different things, but no help. I successfully installed cocoaPods via Terminal and initialised a pod file. After figuring out how to solve "import Firebase error", now I have difficulties with simple operations like trying to write data into database. [Xcode error when trying to write data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77gBf.png)

[My pod file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrxIT.png)

Comment: You shouldnt use this version of Firebase, remove the version number in Podfile and use the latest version (3.something i guess), also the syntax changed a little but it is definitely much more user friendly and all informations are available on firebase websiite

Comment: @Alen are you able to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

The new Firebase SDK 3.2.0 has several breaking changes compared to the old version 2.x, therefore the old Quick Start guide is completely obsolete. All classes have been renamed, and the integration process is different. So use new pod file. It will help you.
You can also do it by adding them directly which is also mentioned on there original web site.

You must follow the new guide on firebase.google.com instead.