# Firebase error with swift code

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have try everythng and I have imported pods to my project, done it several times in several new projects, but always get this error:

'Cannot call value of non-function type 'module'

Is it possible that my cocoa-pods are damaged somehow?
When I insert this code:

import Firebase

```
let BASE_URL = "my_project_url"
var FIREBASE_REF = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

I can see in Output/Debug window that I am connected with firebase, but when I start with code:

```
let BASE_URL = "my_project_url"

let FIREBASE_REF = Firebase(url: BASE_URL)

var CURRENT_USER: Firebase
{
    let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") as! String

    let currentUser = Firebase(url: "\(FIREBASE_REF)").childByAppendingPath("users").childByAppendingPath(userID)

    return currentUser!
}
```

always get error. I have really try stuff from a lot tutorials, I tried a lot of things over past few days and nothing happened.

I have also look and read this topics, but did not help:

[Cannot call value of non-function type 'module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330220/cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-modulefirebase/37437790#37437790)

[xcode error : Cannot call value of non-function type module Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631070/xcode-error-cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-module-firebase)

[Unable to connect Firebase to my Xcode swift app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347572/unable-to-connect-firebase-to-my-xcode-swift-app)

[image: image code]

I have open many new projects, done it import pod many times, I have import pod with insert in my pod file:

```
pod "Firebase"
```

and like this:

```
pod "Firebase"
pod "Firebase/Database"
```

also tried like this:

```
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'
pod "Firebase/Database"
```

but always the same problem. Pods are inserted, I see Firebase folder and I know this is OK, so what could be wrong?
Like I said, I see that I am connected with Firebase in Debug window, as soon I start coding, error appears, and it is in every project like this, even when I try different approach and  different code.

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to call the function inside a class like for ex your ViewController

Comment: update pod once i had same problem and i have got solution by updating pod

Comment: You seem to be mixing Firebase 3.x (`FIRDatabase.database().reference()`) with Firebase 2.x (`Firebase(url: BASE_URL)`), which will not work. Pick a version (see docs for [2.x](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) or [3.x](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start)) and stick with that.

Comment: Thanks guys. This helps a lot. I'll try with Firebase 3.x code, because I am using latest Firebase pods.

Thanks again ;)

Comment: @AnjaliBhimani thanks for tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either using the wrong version of Firebase, or following the wrong guide, depending on what you're trying to do.

Your pod config will install the latest version (3.2.1) while the code you've written is for 2.5.1 and before.

Comment: Thank you. I'll change the code and use code for latest version. This helps a lot, because I didn't know what was wrong, at least now I know that I was mixing codes.